# .NET Check if Full Text Filter Daemon launcher running

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Is there a way to know if Full Text Service is running under MSSQL server from C# code? 
I have tried Server.FullTextService.State with no luck. Thanks

Ok getting service state from ServiceController works fine on local machine, but if you want to find out if the service is running on remote it fails.

One soulution is to query sys.dm_server_services:

```
  select status_desc from sys.dm_server_services WHERE filename LIKE '%fdlauncher.exe%'

  select status_desc from sys.dm_server_services WHERE service_account = 'NT service\MSSQLFDLauncher'
```

Please note that this method might not work for Full-text Service on some SQL 2012 instances:

http://sqlandme.com/tag/sys-dm_server_services/
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2611/sql-services-status-check--an-evolution-part-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this service is run on local system you can just check it with following code:

```
 using System.ServiceProcess;

 ...

        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQLSERVER2012");

        switch (sc.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                Console.WriteLine("Running");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Else");
                break;
        }
```

You can check service name in windows services.

EDIT:
To check service names automatically use following code:

```
DataTable dt = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
ServiceController sc
foreach(DataRow d in dt.Rows)
{
 string instance = dr["InstanceName"].ToString();
 sc = new ServiceController("MSSQLFDLauncher$"+instance );

 switch (sc.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                Console.WriteLine("MSSQLFDLauncher for" + instance + "is Running");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("MSSQLFDLauncher for" + instance + "is NOT Running");
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i worked. The name of the serivce was "MSSQLFDLauncher"

Comment: Rafał.S, your method worked as charm. But is there a way to definately know the name of Msql Service? It seems that on different machines names can differ.

Comment: According to this blog [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx) SQL Server services always have a same name and if the local machine has more than one SQL Server instances then service name follows this pattern: [service_name]$[named_instance] ie. MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQL2012

Comment: Yeah, thanks again for that naming pattern Rafal, it was really helpfull. I have also found that if we want to get running services on a remote server it's better to query it using sys.dm_server_services. Because ServiceController can only retreive services running on current machine as I understand

Comment: I'm glad that I could be helpful. Please mark this post as answered and add the information about sys.dm_server_services to your first post so if anyone else has the same problem he might have to spend on it less time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have found good solution here:
 http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2611/sql-services-status-check---an-evolution-part-3/
    You can use a query like this if not sure about service name (works for MSSQL Server 2008R2 and 2012):

```
 select status_desc from sys.dm_server_services WHERE filename LIKE '%fdlauncher.exe%'

 select status_desc from sys.dm_server_services WHERE service_account = 'NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher'
```

There is a slight downside (bug) on some MSSQL 2012 (Denali) servers sys.dm_server_services only returns status for SQL Server Agents
More details here:
http://sqlandme.com/tag/sys-dm_server_services/
Hope this will help someone!